# filtering pdf links from html source code

Tags: java, html, hyperlink

im about to write a class that takes a look on the html source code and filters all pdf links from it. the idea behind it is just take the parent link + the relative link..
basically it's working for

```
<a href="blabla/123.pdf">pdf</a>
```

but in some cases it doesn't e.g. if the same pdf link is written as

```
<a href="./blabla/123.pdf">pdf</a>
```

or

```
<a href=" blabla/123.pdf">pdf</a>
```

(point and space) both are working links and goes to the same pdf in the same directory if they are parsed in browsers, but for the composition in my class completely useless.

i fixed the problem for the two cases above. the question is if there are other special cases in syntax where i should pay attention on.

Comment: `http://site.com/foobar.pdf`?

Comment: Basically it is all about [relative and absolute paths](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/relative_and_absolute_urls.php3), and all possible characters I can think of are '.' '..' and their mutation.

Comment: take a look at the 3rd link.. if i click on the link in the browser it redirects me to the right pdf, but if i put www.example.com/folder/ blabla/123.pdf to the link bar, i can't access the file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not know what the link points to until you download the file.

I can have a link like `http://www.mysite.com/pages/brochure.html` which internally redirects to a PDF file.

So, if you're not in control of the links, or working on a particular section of your site, you're going to fail.

On the other hand, if you're working on a specific section of the site, where you know every PDF link has a `.pdf` estension, you can simply check the extension and not the whole path (don't know how's written in Java the `.lastIndexOf("string")` thing of C#).